# Непонятные горизонтальные линии вокруг background (image) на мобильных

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Доброго времени суток,

Не могу разобраться, почему при просмотре сайта через планшет/телефон, появляются горизонтальные линии над и под фоновым изображением.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`background:url('/images/cutheader.png') repeat-x top, #FAEBD7 url('/images/cutfooter.png') repeat-x bottom;`

При этом на ПК в любом браузере такой проблемы нет.

Вот  сайт, чтобы эмулировать отображение через IOS:
[Сайт](http://www.mobilephoneemulator.com/)
Вот сам сайт с проблемой:
[Сайт](http://geassnovels.ru/)

Полоски видны сразу под хедером и в футере.

Чтобы пример заработал, увеличьте масштаб до 200% ctrl+Колёсико мыши в хроме.

```css
.head {
  background-color:red;
}
.body {
   padding: 15px 5px;
 background: url('http://geassnovels.ru/images/cutheader.png') repeat-x top, #FAEBD7 url('/images/cutfooter.png') repeat-x bottom;
 flex-grow: 1;
    -webkit-background-size: 11px 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class='head'>
 Hello
</div>
<div class='body'>

</div>
```

Comment: `header {
    margin-bottom: -1px;}`

Comment: Ничего не поменялось...

Comment: Вы смотрите через эмулятор? С пк всё ок...

Comment: Через эмулятор, при чем полоса эта есть только если масштаб задавать больше 100%

Comment: Да нет, Display wished : device-width
Website Width : 375.  Такая же проблема на планшете/телефоне.

Comment: возможно треугольники как-то по высоте не совпадают, попробуйте один бг, а не составной

Comment: Какой браузер-то? Желательно с версией. Вероятно, его глюк.

Comment: Хром PC, ну и любой андройд

Comment: так уберите background-size и линии пропадают. Не стоит тянуть фон непропорционально, сделайте картинки 2x и 30*16 и тогда background-size: 15*8

Comment: это я для воспроизведения бага, у меня нет такого правила. Я конечно в шоке, такая мелочь, а столько головной боли...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Было 2 проблемы:
1)margin-bottom: -1px; в ссылках (css)
2)кривой ресайз (решилось использование SVG)

Comment: У вас был кривой ресайз сначала в браузере, потом вы криво заресайзили в фотошопе; )

Answer (score 2):

Это эмулятор косячный, проверьте в инспекторе хрома. 
На девайсе в порядке, в xcode эмуле тоже

[image: ![iPhone]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxkty.png)
[[image: iPad]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6l7T.jpg)
[[image: iPad]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8B0XJ.jpg)

Comment: Блин, у меня сейчас под рукой планшет и телефон на андройде с хромом. И там и там эти линии :(  Возможно планшеты с ios нормально отображают...

Comment: Странновато. На десктопе в хроме без бага http://s008.radikal.ru/i306/1610/06/f0a249cd3289.jpg
Сделайте бекграунд треугольника тогда ретинареди, вырежите его под ретину и добавьте правила. Мб поможет.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую. На планшете только в файрфоксе нормально отображается, но изображения какие-то квадратные становятся, будто качество уменьшили. Потом отпишу.

Comment: Смог повторить проблему в обычном браузере, уменьшив размер изображения с помощью: -webkit-background-size: 11px 11px; С svg столько мороки, неужели нет другого способа?

Comment: Сделайте изображение под ретину. egorkhmelev.github.io/retina Вырезайте изображение больше, потом пишите правило и указывайте уже размер по умолчанию тот который нужно отобразить. https://habrahabr.ru/post/150071/  https://habrahabr.ru/post/150071/  Качество низкое из за того что соотношение пикселей разное, на иос девайсах плотность пикселей больше, по этому делайте изображение в по ширине и высоте  2 раза больше, ну а дальше как я и писал потом используйте правила для этого изображения

Answer (score 1):

Это не глюк браузера, это неправильное павило.

```
.body {
  background: url('../images/defaultIMAGE.png') repeat-x top, #FAEBD7 url('../images/defaultIMAGE.png') repeat-x bottom;
}

@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
   .body {
       background: url('../images/retinaIMAGE-2x.png') repeat-x top, #FAEBD7 url('../images/retinaIMAGE-2x.png') repeat-x bottom;
       -webkit-background-size: 30px 15px;
          -moz-background-size: 30px 15px;
               background-size: 30px 15px;
    }
}
```

Либо по дефолту ставьте изображение большое например 60px на 30px а в бекграунд-сайз прописывайте 30px на 15px, правило для мобильных дивайсов

```
.body {
  background: url('../images/retinaIMAGE-2x.png') repeat-x top, #FAEBD7 url('../images/retinaIMAGE-2x.png') repeat-x bottom;
  background-size: 30px 15px;
}
@media
  only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2),
  only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio:2),
  only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio:2/1),
  only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio:2),
  only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi),
  only screen and (min-resolution:2dppx){
    .body {
         background-size: 30px 15px;
    }
}
```

Comment: всё-же для таких картинок у вас css тяжелее, чем 2x картинка выйдет и куча лапши. И это не глюк браузера, да, это особенность его ресайза, он делает паттерн с повторением из-за чего на недробной высоте появляются линии.

Comment: я пробовал уменьшать - это не работает, сижу блин сейчас рисую SVG :) и медиа тоже пробовал

Comment: Забавно, увеличил ширину на 1px, появилась полоса и на PC (очень плохо видно, присмотритесь): http://geassnovels.ru/

Comment: @enhaster, вы сейчас в фотошопе как раз просимулировали как работает ресайз хрома.

Comment: не только хрома, один firefox смог в изображение :( Плохо что не работает уменьшение большего изображения, как вы советовали :(